# Labeling for multilabel image classification

Tags: datasets

with a friend of mine, we got in an argument over how to label images for multi-label.

***Note:***
***Groups of a species*** and the species of **catfish** is important to recognize.

The labels are:

- 'I': an individual fish of any type except catfish
- 'R': A group of **same species**
- 'K': Catfish

**First conflict:**

For an image containing a bank of fish, our conflicting opinions are:

1. I and R
2. R

**Second conflict:**

If in an image there's actually a bank of catfish, our conflicting opinions are:

1. K and R
2. K

**Third conflict:**

If in an image there's actually a group of same species of fish and other individual fish from different species, our conflicting opinions are:

1. R
2. I and R

**Summary**:

- I think one very important difference of opinion here, is if in multi-label, we should give two labels to one object in image(say group and fish) or if an object should have only one label.
- Should the overwhelming presence of an object, overshadow the presence of another (group of fish of same species and another individual fish)

What do you think?